# Is it "hadn't been meant for me to read" or "hadn't been meant for me to read it"?

Tags: grammar

What the correct form?

Example sentence:

> The letter hadn’t been meant for me to read (it), but wouldn’t it be
>   worse if no one did?

Comment: Can you tell us why you think that the pronoun "it" might be included in the first clause of your sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't include the *it*. *It* is (usually) a pronoun referring to a noun given elsewhere. In this sentence, it would refer to *the letter*, and since *the letter* is already in the sentence, you don't need to refer to it. If you change the sentence to remove the prepositional phrase (*for me to read*), this becomes clearer:

> I hadn't been meant to read the letter, but wouldn't it be worse if no one did?

However, this sentence is also correct, which can lead to confusion:

> It hadn't been meant for me to read the letter, but wouldn't it be worse if no one did?

In this case, you are using the *prop it* or *dummy it*, similar to phrases such as *it is raining* or *it is a long way to town*. We use this when we don't care what the subject of the sentence is.